# JSON Data not populating correctly

Tags: json, angularjs

I am getting data from the test2 JSON file which populates correctly. However, I want to click on a resulting table entry and make a div table appear with charges relevant to that customer but all I get is:

```
Account             Chargecode           Rate

{{ x.Customer }}    {{ x.ChargeCode }}  {{ x.Charge }}
```

AngularJS

```
//angularjs to fetch JSON data
//data for main table(this works)

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http:///test2.aspx")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.recds = response.data.records;
    });

//function to make DIV visible and display charge data (data not displayed)

    $scope.wkdata1=function(ac) {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = 'visible';

        var app2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);
        app2.controller('charges', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http:/charges.aspx")
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.chg = response.data.records2;
                });
        });
    
    };
});
```

HTML for charges

```
<div id="div1" class="block2" ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="charges">
 <table>
   <tr>
   <th>Account</th>
   <th>Chargecode</th>
   <th>Rate</th>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="x in chg">
   <td>{{ x.Customer }}</td>
   <td>{{ x.ChargeCode }}</td>
   <td>{{ x.Charge }}</td>
 </tr>  
 </table>
</div>
```

Note: both json files pulls back data when run in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

You're injecting multiple angular apps into one website. While this is possible, it's not very direct. Not sure if you really need to that here, but if you really want to you need to bootstrap the second angular project into the page.

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('div1'), ['myApp2']);
```

Again, with you having all the data you need within one AngularJS application its best to make controllers and directives as needed rather than an additional AngularJS app.

Comment: Hi, yes, I did try it without the second app but the result was just the same.in that the data was not displayed. This is my first use of Angular so any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jcL4z6vu/1/  You can use this as a basis. Whenever I create a new controller, I add a console.log('Testing controller') to verify my file is created accordingly. One of your other issues, ng-controller="charges", needs to be ng-controller="customerCtrl". You need the controller name, not a variable on the scope. Probably a simple copy and paste error. Whenever the interpolation isnt working as expected, (ie, seeing the {{ x.Customer }} in your HTML), its likely your AngularJS components are not set up correctly or there is a javascript error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.  Narrowed it down to the fact that it is not loading the second controller but don't know why as it is exactly the same as the first but with a different JSON file. Is it because it is nested in the first?

Comment: https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/angularjs-newbie-second-json-datasource-does-not-display.973715/    ...more complete code listing

Comment: Get rid of your second AngularJS application. Here is an updated example with your data. https://jsfiddle.net/jcL4z6vu/1/  Note the ng-app is located at the <html>

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I think this is the same example as before.

Comment: Ok, I have the data returned for the second table as proved with an alert(JSON.stringify($scope.chgs)); but it still does not display on the second table???

Comment: Sorry about that. The 2nd link was not updated as expected.
https://jsfiddle.net/sgukhLd6/  this is an updated link to a working example of a button calling an API and filling a table with the file name and its image.